# How to insert a "marquee" tag in this given code?

Tags: html, scroll, tags, marquee

i need to insert a marquee tag at our company site so the news table will scroll.
i have tried to place it in several places but it didn't work.
need your help on where to place it.
this is the code:

```
> <table border="0" cellspacing="1"
> cellpadding="1"><tbody><tr><td><div><span style="font-size:
> 14px;"><span style="color: #a5cd38;"><strong><span style="color:
> #a5cd38;"><img src="/sites/default/files/arrow2.jpg" alt="" align="right" width="15">&nbsp;חדשות
> ואירועים</span></strong></span></span></div><div><span
> style="font-size: 14px;"><span style="color: #a5cd38;"><strong><span
> style="color: #a5cd38;"><br></span></strong></span></span></div><div
> style="text-align: right;"><span style="font-size: x-small; color:
> #99cc00;">&nbsp;4/11/15</span></div><div><span style="font-size: x-small;">בקרוב, יעלה לאויר פורטל משאבי אנוש חדשני
> ומתקדם</span></div><div><span style="font-size:
> x-small;"><br></span></div><div><span style="color: #99cc00;
> font-size: x-small;">1/9/15</span></div><div><span style="color:
> #333333; font-size: x-small;">עליית מערכות בדנאל - מערכת "רקורד" לניהול משאבי אנוש ומערכת "המדריך" לניהול מערך הדרכות, עלו בהצלחה לאויר
> בחברת דנאל</span></div><div><span style="color: #333333; font-size:
> x-small;"><br></span></div><div><span style="color: #99cc00;
> font-size: x-small;">15/8/15</span></div><div><span style="color:
> #333333; font-size: x-small;">פרויקט בית המשפט - מערכות בית המשפט העליון שודרגו בהצלחה לגרסת
> XPA/XPI&nbsp;</span></div></td></tr></tbody></table><p>&nbsp;</p>
```

i was reading some manuals about marquee but still didn't succeed.

Comment: The <marquee> tag is obsolete. More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee

Comment: i'll be glad if you could recommend me about another option so the block will scroll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to give marquee tag like below.

```
<table>  <tr>   <td><div class="marquee"><marquee direction="up" height="100" width="400" ><strong>XXX</strong><br />XXX</marquee></div></td>  </tr></table>
```

Comment: sorry, but i don't have much knowledge about html. where should i place it at the given code?

Comment: Refer this below tutorial.   [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_marquee_tag.htm)       [link](http://www.way2tutorial.com/html/html_marquee_tag.php)

Comment: thanks but still no luck. tried placing it at some places in the code but everything just disappears from the block when i save it.

Comment: Try this below code for single image.    <table border="0" cellspacing="1"> <tbody> <tr><td><marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left"><img src="../jix/img_nat.png" width="120" height="80" alt="Natural" /></marquee></td> </tr></table>

Comment: thanks! starting to look good. now i changed the "diretion left" to "down" and it works for a second and only when i press another button in the site